Cypress Stubbing custom class does not work
I am trying to stub the return methods of a class , but they do not seem to be stubbed when I print the return values in the console. My test class :
// MyCustomClass.ts
class MyCustomClass {
  // Define a static method
  public static myMethod(): string {
    return "MyCustomClass myMethod value";
  }

  // Define an instance method
  public anotherMethod(): string {
    return "MyCustomClass anotherMethod value";
  }
}

if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  (window as any).MyCustomClass = MyCustomClass;
}

export default MyCustomClass;


globals.d.ts contains :
export {}; // Make this a module
declare global {
  // Extend the Window interface in Cypress to include MyCustomClass
  interface Window {
    MyCustomClass: typeof MyCustomClass;
  }
}



The test file :
import MyCustomClass from "ts/services/managers/MyCustomClass";
// Attach MyCustomClass to the window object
 let mainPage: MainPage;
describe("set work schedule", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {

    cy.window().then((win) => {
      win.MyCustomClass = MyCustomClass;
    }); 

    cy.window().should((win) => {
      console.log("on load");
      console.log(win.MyCustomClass);
      expect(win.MyCustomClass).to.exist; // passes
    });

    // Stub static and instance methods
    cy.window().then((win) => {
      cy.stub(win.MyCustomClass, "myMethod").returns("stubbed static value");
      cy.stub(win.MyCustomClass.prototype, "anotherMethod").returns("stubbed instance value");
    });

    // Verify the methods return the stubbed values
    cy.window().then((win) => {
      const staticResult = win.MyCustomClass.myMethod();
      expect(staticResult).to.equal("stubbed static value");

      const instance = new win.MyCustomClass();
      const instanceResult = instance.anotherMethod();
      expect(instanceResult).to.equal("stubbed instance value");
    });


console.log(MyCustomClass.myMethod()) // stubbed value

 mainPage = new MainPage();
 mainPage.open(); // -> calls console.log(MyCustomClass.myMethod()) and shows original value , not the stubbed
  });


      it("Test something", () => {
           console.log(MyCustomClass.myMethod()) // stubbed value
      });


1.In the test "Test something" the value is correctly stubbed , however in the mainPage.open() after a lot of chained calls , eventually   MyCustomClass.myMethod() is printed, but the value is not stubbed yet it shows the original one , what can be the reason behind this? Is it possible that mainPage.open() doesn't know about the stubbing? I have access to the file that prints MyCustomClass.myMethod() inside the mainPage().open() and I want to make it use the stubbed value.
So TLDR the beforeEach() stubs correctly , mainPage.open() is called and prints MyCustomClass.myMethod() which shows the original value , in the test we print MyCustomClass.myMethod() and it is the stubbed value

You have missed out the code for MainPage, but I'm going to assume the open() method performs a cy.visit() which changes the win returned from cy.window(), so you are stubbing too early.
See Window Before Load shows how to stub correctly using the window:before:load event.
You also do not need the noisy assignment to win, at least for static methods.
MainPage
import MyCustomClass from './my-class'

class MainPage {
  public open(): void {
    cy.visit('https://example.com')
      .then(() => {
        // make sure you console.log after the window:before:load event
        // i.e after the stub is set up
        console.log('From MainPage (myMethod): ', MyCustomClass.myMethod())
      })
  }
}
export default MainPage;

Test
let mainPage: MainPage;
describe('stubs the static method', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {

    Cypress.on('window:before:load', () => {
      console.log('From "window:before:load" event')
      cy.stub(MyCustomClass, 'myMethod').returns('stubbed static value')
    })

    mainPage = new MainPage()
    mainPage.open() 
  })

  it('Test something', () => {
    console.log('From the test: ', MyCustomClass.myMethod()) 
    expect(MyCustomClass.myMethod()).to.eq('stubbed static value')
  })
})

Cypress runner

Console


I tested the things you mentioned and they work , however when I visit the url indeed the value is stubbed , but then once visiting the URL, a number request responses are send to my backend which triggers the codebase and there the static method does not return the stubbed value

it turns out , that inside mainPage.open() wheere I call cy.visit('https://example.com') none of the onLoad, onBeforeLoad methods show that the class is loaded in the windows so I magically after the opening of the site did cy.wait(200000) for 20 seconds during which the class is loaded but it still not used and after this wait I stub and then the MyCustomClass.myMethod to return the desired value , the stub is applied and then MyCustomClass.myMethod() is called from mainPage.open() chain with the stubbed value .
